# Add property to object when it's not null

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm working on a small API and I want to update the data using `HTTP PATCH REQUEST` without using a bunch of if statements. I'm trying to fill the outgoing data object with the changed data only.

```
update() {
    let prop1 = hasBeenChanged.prop1 ? changedData.prop1 : null;
    // ...
    let propN = hasBeenChanged.propN ? changedData.propN : null;

    let data: ISomething = {
        // something like --> property != null ? property: property.value : nothing
    }
}
```

Is there any way to create the data object dynamically?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could use `Object.assign` in combination with the ternary operator:

```
let data = Object.assign({},
  first === null ? null : {first},
  ...
);
```

This works because `Object.assign` will skip over `null` parameters.

If you are sure that the property value is not going to be "falsy", then it would be bit shorter to write:

```
let data = Object.assign({},
  first && {first},
  ...
);
```

Assuming the object is going to be stringified at some point, since stringification ignores undefined values, you could also try

```
let data = {
  first: first === null ? undefined : first,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got it now. I forgot to tell that I'm using typescript and I thought it's going to be similar, but there is no Object.assign function in the ObjectConstructor of typescript when I'm compiling to ES5. I did it with your tip about the stringified data. When I set the data to undefined and not null, they haven't been stringified which was great and easy! Thank you!

Comment: Should the `||` in the first code segment be `:` per typical ternary construction?  Or is this some other sorcery that I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 56):

Depending on the JS version you are using, you can use the spread operator `...`

```
const getData = data => ({
  ...data.first  && { 'Custom First Prop Name': data.first },
  ...data.second && { 'Custom Second Prop Name': data.second },
  ...data.third  && { third: data.third },
  ...data.fourth && { fourth: data.fourth },
});
```

Answer (score 13):

### Non-inline solution

If you don't need to add the value inline, it is pretty straightforward and clean to write your assignment like this.

```
const val1 = 1
const val2
const data = {}

val1 && (data.a = val1) // 1
val2 && (data.b = val2) // Not added
// data = { a : 1 }
```

> NOTE: This will not work if the value is falsey

Comment: Paranthesis was what I missed

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy way:

```
const example = {
   ...(foo?.bar && {nested: 1})
}
```